# "Links to jsfiddle.net must be accompanied by code." Not correct imo.

Tags: discussion

I have stumbled upon this issue many times, when I ask a question accompanied by a JSfiddle I must insert code.
This is in my opinion not needed because :

- The JSFiddle contains code
- Some "short" coded code's do not need clarification.
- Code can make the article more confusing.

IMO, this should be deleted.

[image: Links to jsfiddle.net must be accompanied by code.]

Comment: What happens if the JSFiddle link doesn't work? Then there is no code for users to reference.

Comment: Giving -1 just because you don't have the same opinion is not why -1 was made.
It's made for giving bad questions a bad rating...

Comment: @JpHouten actually on Meta sites, voting can be based on opinion.  But you don't earn or lose rep, so it does not impact your privileges at all

Comment: Downvotes on Meta are different. They mean disagreement, in this case most users probably don't like that you are requesting this to be deleted.

Comment: @bluefeet first off, I never stated that you are not allowed to post code with your jsfiddle.
Secondly, the OP needs to make sure the link works, otherwise he/she needs to fix it.

Comment: Most users do not want to have to go to another site to get the information needed to answer your question.  You can use the Fiddle link to help demonstrate your problem and clarify, but visiting the link should not required to answer the question.  If you have too much code to put in the question, then you probably need to go back and do some more research to limit the scope of the code.

Comment: @psubsee2003 didn't knew that, thought it worked the same on every overflow site, my bad!

Comment: @JpHouten When an external link is provided there is no guarantee that the website will be up and working....that's the problem.

Comment: @psubsee2003 I can see why people do not want to go to another website to see the code, but wether it should be implemented should be a choice of the OP not the community/overflow makers.

Comment: @JpHouten and just because the link works today doesn't mean it will work 6 months from now or 6 years from now.  If you rely on the fiddle for the entire context of the question, then the link breaks in the future, no one will be able to understand how or why the answers address your question

Comment: @psubsee2003 still I stand by my opinion, if the link broke somehow, the community can comment on the question and the OP will get noticed by it.

Comment: @JpHouten Ummm... actually it is precisely the Stack Overflow owners of the site, with input from the community, who are ultimately responsible for the content and character of the website. It is their right to run it as they see fit.

Comment: @JpHouten _"the community can comment on the question and the OP will get noticed by it"_ and what if OP no longer has the code? Either "lost" it or changed it so much that it's no longer the same?

Comment: @JpHouten in an ideal world, maybe.  But this is far from an ideal world.  Questions get abandoned or forgotten all the time. Stack Overflow is not designed to help **you** with **your** problems.  It is designed to be a reference source to help everyone with their programming problems.  If you can't understand the answer since the code from the question is missing, how is anyone going be able to understand the problem and the solution?

Comment: @Epodax Thats good point!

Comment: @psubsee2003 We don't live in an ideal world? I am sure I do! haha, still the community should help update old questions or delete obsolete ones, which already happens, but maybe not enough.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Questions and answers should be able to stand alone without an external link. If your question relies on a JSFiddle, you need to copy the code into the question so that people without access to it (JSFiddle is blocked where I currently work) can still understand the question. (Same for answers, naturally.) This isn't something that can be *optional*, since it would potentially break a lot of JavaScript questions for a lot of users.

Comment: JSfiddle block :O why would you do that? If thats the case in why it's build I could see why it's done.

Comment: @JpHouten It's a misguided policy, I agree, but the bank doesn't like us to run their code on other people's machines, or share it with other people.